# Oracle SQL checking field is not a value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and am trying to build out sql that meets the following condition:
If PS_EMPLOYEES.COUNTRY<>USA, enter PS_EMPLOYEES.POSTAL, else, leave blank

The below code does this EXCEPT it checks if the country is equal to USA.  How would I do the opposite?

```
, ZIPCODE = 
    (SELECT decode(t2.COUNTRY, 'USA', t2.POSTAL, ' ') zipcode
    FROM PS_EMPLOYEES t2
...
```

Comment: It might be best to use a case statement in this circumstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could just use a case statement (not oracle specific):

```
, ZIPCODE = 
    (SELECT CASE WHEN t2.COUNTRY != 'USA' THEN t2.POSTAL ELSE ' ' END) zipcode
    FROM PS_EMPLOYEES t2
...
```

Or you could just use the decode differently:

```
, ZIPCODE = 
    (SELECT decode(t2.COUNTRY, 'USA', ' ', t2.POSTAL) zipcode
    FROM PS_EMPLOYEES t2
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use case statement...as below

```
(select (case when t2.country != 'USA' then t2.postal 
             else ' '
        end ) zipcode from PS_EMPLOYEES t2
 ....
```